# Remove encoding from URL with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've found an error in Google Webmaster Tools that I need to redirect. I've done the following, but it will not work. Is there anything else I can try?

I would like http://www.domain.com/blog/category/%E2%80%8E to get redirected to http://www.domain.com/blog/category/

Code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/category/\%E2\%80\%8E$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/blog/category/ [R,L]
```

I've tried a few other potential solution from SO, but with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Replace your rule with this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(blog/category)/%E2%80%8E\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]
```

`THE_REQUEST` represents the original HTTP request as received by the Apache web server.

Comment: This is a properly test code. I suggest you to provide your latest .htaccess in your question so that I can investigate the issue.